# converting multiple text files into a single csv file with two columns

Tags: python-3.x, file, glob

I want to convert multiple text files(in same folder) into a single csv file with column1 as text files' name and column2 as text file's content.

I used the following code to copy the text file contents of text files to excel sheet.

```
import glob

filepaths=list(glob.glob(path+"\*"))

for filepath in filepaths:
    with open("document.csv","a") as fd:
        fd.write(open(filepath,"r").read())
```

Please find the output in the image I attached. I want the text contents of all files to be in a single column and text file names to be in another column. I have little to no experience in file handling. Your help would be highly appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8wWE.png

---

**EDIT:**

Hey Furas, the file paths are being copied perfectly, but the text content is not being copied perfectly. Please find the picture attached below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhSc3.png

Comment: you should tell us what have you done

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: don't use standard `open()` , `write()` to create `csv` file - but use module `csv` for this.. CSV uses `,` to seperate columns, and `new line` to separate rows - you put text from file with `,` and `new line` and it treads them as separators - but this needs to put all in `" "`  - but this makes another problem because text may have own`"` which has to be converted to `\"` - and module `csv` will do it all automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use standard `open()`, `write()` to create `csv` file but use standard module `csv` for this.

`CSV` uses `,` to separate columns, and `new line` to separate rows. You put text from file with `,` and `new line` and `Excel` treads them as separators - and you get text in many rows and columns.

But this needs to put all text in `" "` to escape these special chars (and `Excel` will treat them as normal chars in text. But this makes another problem because text may have own `"` which you would converted to `\"` - but module `csv` will do it all automatically.

```
import glob
import csv

filepaths = list(glob.glob(path+"\*")) 

for filepath in filepaths:
    with open(filepath) as fd:
        text = fd.read()
    with open("document.csv", "a", newline="") as fd:
        writer = csv.writer(fd)
        writer.writerow( [filepath, text] )
```

**EDIT:**

I added `newline=""` in `open()` because some system need it to skip empty rows.
See doc for module [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

If you want to format data in file then you need to use file `.xlsx` instead of `.csv` (because `csv` keeps only data without formattings).
See [Python Resources for working with Excel - Working with Excel Files in Python](https://www.python-excel.org/)

Comment: if you have new problem then you should write it as comment, not edit answer. OR you should write new question on new page and add `@furas` in comments (and it will inform me automatically). Your image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhSc3.png

Comment: If you means it doesn't resize columns to show full path then is not problem with code but with Excel. You have to manually resize columns in Excel. File `.csv` is only for sending data. It doesn't care of formatting. You have to use other modules to create directly file `.xlsx` which can keep formatting. See https://www.python-excel.org/ . (or see `pandas`) And if problem are empty rows then it may need to use `newline` in `open("document.csv", "a", newline="")` (at least on Windows because on Linux I don't need it) See doc for module [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)